# Problem loading neo4j dump in docker container

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-container

I am using docker to launch multiple instances of neo4j instances for my project. 
I have a requirement that I have to load a graph dump to one of my neo4j docker container and I have to do it again an again (as the graph dump will be provided by a separate group of people).

These are my steps that I have followed in order to do the same -

```
    # docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/data:/data \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/logs:/logs \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/conf:/conf \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/plugins:/plugins \
    neo4j:3.3.3

    # docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                                      NAMES
eee581b2f493        neo4j:3.3.3         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 seconds               0.0.0.0:7474->7474/tcp, 7473/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7687->7687/tcp   priceless_ride
```

This brings up the container, but the database is empty. Next I tried the following to load a neo4j dump to my newly built docker container

```
# docker stop priceless_ride
priceless_ride

# cp home/dimension/neo4j/dumps/2018-09-05.dump ~/neo4j/container3/data/

# docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
--volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/data:/data \
--volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/logs:/logs \
--volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/conf:/conf \
--volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/plugins:/plugins \
-i -t neo4j:3.3.3 /bin/bash
```

The above command creates a separate container and runs the container in interactive mode. Once I am inside the container I run -

```
bash-4.4# bin/neo4j-admin load --from=/data/2018-09-05.dump --database=graph.db --force
bash-4.4# exit
```

Now I execute `docker ps -a` command, I will see 2 container in the output

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
073c31c75ff5        neo4j:3.3.3         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 seconds ago       Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                       focused_zhukovsky
eee581b2f493        neo4j:3.3.3         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 hours ago         Exited (0) 7 minutes ago                       priceless_ride
```

I have to remove the newly built container as it is no longer needed. by executing `docker rm focused_zhukovsky`

Every thing works fine, when I restarted my container by executing command

```
# docker start priceless_ride
```

and check the browser using `http://127.0.0.1:7474/browser/`, the container now has the loaded database form the dump.

Following the above steps for loading a graph dump is okay, but its cumbersome if I have to do it again and again. Is their a cleaner way to load neo4j dump without the need to start a separate container in interactive mode and then firing `neo4j-admin load` command.

Is it possible to start the docker container without running the neo4j inside it. If this is possible then I can go inside the container and fire the `neo4j-admin load` command as many time I want.

I am stuck at this problem from quite some time. I will deeply appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

One simple and quick way I can think of right now is to override the default neo4j container command something like this:

```
docker run  -d --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --volume=$HOME/neo4j/datanew:/data neo4j /bin/bash -c "[ -f /data/db.dump ] && /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j-admin load --from=/data/db.dump --database=graph.db --force; neo4j console"
```

You use the -c command with /bin/bash to execute multiple commands.
The [ -f /data/db.dump ] checks if the db dump exists and if does it runs the neo4j dump import command. After this neo4j is started.

Considering that you have a database dump named db.dump in your $HOME/datanew directory neo4j-admin should be able to load it up before starting the neo4j server. Stopping it, replacing the dump with a new one and starting it back up again should bring up the new database.

Pretty sure the same thing can be done if you create your docker image based on the neo4j image and add the command in the end which will do the exact same thing. That should be much cleaner.

Comment: He I tried, but cannot get it working. The container gets started, but no directory except /data/ is being mapped to the respective container directories. Also I am not able to access - http://127.0.0.1:7474/browser/ Also what does -c "[ -f /data/db.dump ] command means. Can you please elaborate the command a little more.

Comment: @AnuragSharma updated answer with additional info.
So, just to clarify in the command that I provided the neo4j directory on the host will live at $HOME/neo4j/datanew .  If you put the database dump file named "db.dump" there and then run the container, it should pick up the dump.
Also stopping the container, updating the dump and starting it again will import it again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the dump was loaded successfully as I am able to see databases/ and dbms/ directories, but I am not able to access http://127.0.0.1:7474/browser/ from the browser.

Comment: @AnuragSharma you mean you were able to access the browser earlier but after following these steps you are not able to?
Can you also check by logging into the container to check if neo4j is actually running?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using Neo4j Community Edition rather than Enterprise Edition hence You are unable to load db dump at run time. This feature is exclusively in Enterprise Edition so in community edition you may need to tweak it.

So before starting neo4j container copy your dump in the path which you are going to mount on container and load it on docker run

```
# cp home/dimension/neo4j/dumps/2018-09-05.dump ~/neo4j/container3/data/

# docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/data:/data \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/logs:/logs \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/conf:/conf \
    --volume=/home/dimension/neo4j/container3/plugins:/plugins \
    -it neo4j:3.3.3 /bin/bash -c "[ -f /data/db.dump ] \
    && /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j-admin load --from=/data/db.dump \
    --database=graph.db --force
```